# How do I use trig in a shader in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, graphics, webgl, shader

Is there a way to use a trig function in shaderSourceText?  Should I include a math library somehow?

```
var shaderSourceText =
[
    //Shader Source Text
].join('\n');

var Shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(Shader,shaderSourceText);
gl.compileShader(Shader);
```

Comment: ps, no reason not to use [multi-line template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for shaders

Answer (score 0):

trig is built into GLSL. See [the spec](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf) and/or end of the [the WebGL reference card](https://www.khronos.org/files/webgl/webgl-reference-card-1_0.pdf)